# I didn't expect "verb"

Tags: sentence-construction

How can I express the idea with accuracy in the situation: I had thought that something would be easy to do but the result literally exceeded my expectations.

Which sentence would be more accurate to express the idea:

1. " I didn't expect cooking shrimps would be so hard"
2. " I didn't expect cooking shrimps to be so hard"
3. " I didn't expect that to cook shrimps would be so hard"
4. " I didn't expect that cooking shrimps would be so hard"

Is there a better way to express the idea besides these ones?

Comment: (2) and (4) are the most idiomatic. (1) might be used in casual speech.

Comment: **Shrimp** is not usually used in the plural.  One shrimp, two shrimp, etc.  (There are some dialects in which it can be made plural.)